# Expanding Rows in Pandas DataFrame based on Time Intervals, Accounting for Optional Breaks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Pandas DataFrame representing timesheets with start and end times, as well as optional rest and meal break intervals. My goal is to expand a single row into multiple rows with correct intervals. It's worth noting that:

- A timesheet might not have any breaks.
- A timesheet might have only a rest break, only a meal break, or both.
- The order of meal and rest breaks can vary (meal break can be both before and after rest break).

Here's an example DataFrame:

| Id | Start Time | End Time | Rest Break Start Time | Rest Break End Time | Meal Break Start Time | Meal Break End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-26 07:59 | 2024-01-26 12:33 | 2024-01-26 10:43 | 2024-01-26 10:53 | 2024-01-26 12:03 | 2024-01-26 12:33 |
| 2 | 2024-01-26 14:29 | 2024-01-26 17:35 | 2024-01-26 16:33 | 2024-01-26 16:44 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 2024-01-26 08:02 | 2024-01-26 12:45 | NaN | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 4 | 2024-01-26 09:15 | 2024-01-26 16:15 | NaN | NaN | 2024-01-26 12:15 | 2024-01-26 12:45 |
| 5 | 2024-01-26 09:10 | 2024-01-26 16:37 | 2024-01-26 15:43 | 2024-01-26 15:55 | 2024-01-26 13:06 | 2024-01-26 13:37 |

The output I need:

| Id | Category | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Session | 2024-01-26 07:59 | 2024-01-26 10:43 |
| 1 | Rest Break | 2024-01-26 10:43 | 2024-01-26 10:53 |
| 1 | Session | 2024-01-26 10:53 | 2024-01-26 12:03 |
| 1 | Meal Break | 2024-01-26 12:03 | 2024-01-26 12:33 |
| 2 | Session | 2024-01-26 14:29 | 2024-01-26 16:33 |
| 2 | Rest Break | 2024-01-26 16:33 | 2024-01-26 16:44 |
| 2 | Session | 2024-01-26 16:44 | 2024-01-26 17:35 |
| 3 | Session | 2024-01-26 08:02 | 2024-01-26 12:45 |
| 4 | Session | 2024-01-26 09:15 | 2024-01-26 12:15 |
| 4 | Meal Break | 2024-01-26 12:15 | 2024-01-26 12:45 |
| 4 | Session | 2024-01-26 12:45 | 2024-01-26 16:15 |
| 5 | Session | 2024-01-26 09:10 | 2024-01-26 13:06 |
| 5 | Meal Break | 2024-01-26 13:06 | 2024-01-26 13:37 |
| 5 | Session | 2024-01-26 13:37 | 2024-01-26 15:43 |
| 5 | Rest Break | 2024-01-26 15:43 | 2024-01-26 15:55 |
| 5 | Session | 2024-01-26 15:55 | 2024-01-26 16:37 |

My current logic involves extracting all unique datetimes from each row, sorting them, and creating intervals. While this approach somewhat works, I'm struggling with assigning a 'Category' column to each interval.

```
import pandas as pd

# Your original DataFrame

data = {'Id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'Start Time': ['2024-01-26 07:59', '2024-01-26 14:29', '2024-01-26 08:02', '2024-01-26 09:15', '2024-01-26 09:10'],
    'End Time': ['2024-01-26 12:33', '2024-01-26 17:35', '2024-01-26 12:45', '2024-01-26 16:15', '2024-01-26 16:37'],
    'Rest Break Start Time': ['2024-01-26 10:43', '2024-01-26 16:33', None, None, '2024-01-26 15:43'],
    'Rest Break End Time': ['2024-01-26 10:53', '2024-01-26 16:44', None, None, '2024-01-26 15:55'],
    'Meal Break Start Time': ['2024-01-26 12:03', None, None, '2024-01-26 12:15', '2024-01-26 13:06'],
    'Meal Break End Time': ['2024-01-26 12:33', None, None, '2024-01-26 12:45', '2024-01-26 13:37']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create an empty DataFrame to store the expanded rows

expanded_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id', 'Start Time', 'End Time'])

# Iterate through each row of the original DataFrame

for index, row in df.iterrows():

    id_value = row['Id']
    start_time = pd.to_datetime(row['Start Time'])
    end_time = pd.to_datetime(row['End Time'])

    # Collect all times

    times = {start_time, end_time}
    for column in ['Rest Break Start Time', 'Rest Break End Time', 'Meal Break Start Time', 'Meal Break End Time']:
        if not pd.isna(row[column]):
            times.add(pd.to_datetime(row[column]))

    # Sort the times

    sorted_times = sorted(times)

    # Create intervals

    for i in range(len(sorted_times) - 1):
        if sorted_times[i] != sorted_times[i + 1]:
            expanded_df = expanded_df.append({'Id': id_value, 'Start Time': sorted_times[i], 'End Time': sorted_times[i + 1]}, ignore_index=True)

# Sort the expanded DataFrame by 'Id' and 'Start Time'

expanded_df = expanded_df.sort_values(by=['Id', 'Start Time']).reset_index(drop=True)

# Show the result

expanded_df
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated version that computes the category by checking the column names for "Start Time"/"End Time":

```py
rows = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    id_value = row["Id"]
    start_time = pd.to_datetime(row["Start Time"])
    end_time = pd.to_datetime(row["End Time"])

    # Collect all times

    times = {(start_time, "Start Time"), (end_time, "End Time")}
    for column in [
        "Rest Break Start Time",
        "Rest Break End Time",
        "Meal Break Start Time",
        "Meal Break End Time",
    ]:
        if not pd.isna(row[column]):
            times.add((pd.to_datetime(row[column]), column))

    # Sort the times

    sorted_times = sorted(times)

    # Create intervals

    for i in range(len(sorted_times) - 1):
        c1 = sorted_times[i][1]

        if "Start Time" in c1:
            cat = c1.replace("Start Time", "").strip() or "Session"
        elif "End Time" in c1:
            cat = "Session"

        if sorted_times[i][0] != sorted_times[i + 1][0]:
            rows.append(
                {
                    "Id": id_value,
                    "Category": cat,
                    "Start Time": sorted_times[i][0],
                    "End Time": sorted_times[i + 1][0],
                }
            )

expanded_df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
# Sort the expanded DataFrame by 'Id' and 'Start Time'

expanded_df = expanded_df.sort_values(by=["Id", "Start Time"]).reset_index(drop=True)

# Show the result

print(expanded_df)
```

Prints:

```
    Id    Category          Start Time            End Time
0    1     Session 2024-01-26 07:59:00 2024-01-26 10:43:00
1    1  Rest Break 2024-01-26 10:43:00 2024-01-26 10:53:00
2    1     Session 2024-01-26 10:53:00 2024-01-26 12:03:00
3    1  Meal Break 2024-01-26 12:03:00 2024-01-26 12:33:00
4    2     Session 2024-01-26 14:29:00 2024-01-26 16:33:00
5    2  Rest Break 2024-01-26 16:33:00 2024-01-26 16:44:00
6    2     Session 2024-01-26 16:44:00 2024-01-26 17:35:00
7    3     Session 2024-01-26 08:02:00 2024-01-26 12:45:00
8    4     Session 2024-01-26 09:15:00 2024-01-26 12:15:00
9    4  Meal Break 2024-01-26 12:15:00 2024-01-26 12:45:00
10   4     Session 2024-01-26 12:45:00 2024-01-26 16:15:00
11   5     Session 2024-01-26 09:10:00 2024-01-26 13:06:00
12   5  Meal Break 2024-01-26 13:06:00 2024-01-26 13:37:00
13   5     Session 2024-01-26 13:37:00 2024-01-26 15:43:00
14   5  Rest Break 2024-01-26 15:43:00 2024-01-26 15:55:00
15   5     Session 2024-01-26 15:55:00 2024-01-26 16:37:00
```

Comment: thank you very much. Your solution works great. However, there is an issue, if Meal Break Start Time or Rest Break Start Time are the same as Start Time (when sessions starts with Break). In this case, it assigns "Session" category instead of "Meal Break" or "Rest Break". Can you please help me to modify the code? Thank you.

Comment: @Yara1994 I suggest to open a new question here on SO and put there what have you tried. I try to look at it.